# re.findall working in console but not in script?

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm probably missing something very basic here, but here goes:

I'm using Python 2.7 and regex to identify digits within a string.

In the console, I type in:

```
>>> newstr = 'NukeNews/File_132.txt'
>>> int(re.findall(r'\d+',newstr)[0])
132
```

Which is what I expect.

However, in the script I'm running, I have the strings stored in a dictionary, linedict. I'm running this script:

```
news_id=[]

for line in line_vec:
    print linedict[line]
    newstr= linedict[line]
    id_int = re.findall('r\d+',newstr)
    print id_int
    news_id.append(id_int)
```

It's a long list, but the output looks like:

```
NukeNews/File_132.txt
[]
```

So - the correct string is registered, but it's not matching on anything.

I was calling the first item in the list earlier (to match the console input of  `int(re.findall(r'\d+',newstr)[0])`, but the script is telling me that the regex didn't find any instances of the digits in the string. I would expect this to return:
     NukeNews/File_132.txt
     ['132']

Any idea why it's not working as expected? When I try running `re.match(r'/d+',newstr)` I also get an empty group (following the groups example on https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

**Edit:** As pointed out, this is a case of not being careful with `'r'` and `r'*'`. I'm just going to leave this up in case anyone else googling "why does my regex work in console but not in script" forgets to check this typo, like I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your `r` inside the quotes so instead of getting a "raw string" you're getting a string with an `'r'` in it ...

```
id_int = re.findall('r\d+',newstr)
#                    ^
# should be:
id_int = re.findall(r'\d+',newstr)
```

your "console" version also only takes the first of the found matches compared to your "script" version which appends the entire list.

Comment: Oh yikes, that's mortifying. Thank you. That was exactly the issue. :)